# AngularJS, scopes, directive calling parent controller function

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, directive

What the heck is going on here?

I'm trying to call a function defined on a parent scope's controller through a child directive. For some reason '&' is failing me?

The controller's html:

```
<div ng-controller="facetCtrl">
    <header>
        <div facet></div>
        <div facet></div>
    </header>
</div>
```

The facet directive's html:

```
<div ng-click="selectFacet($event)" notify="facetGroupSelected(facet)">
    <div>{{ name }}</div>
</div>
```

The controller's coffee:

```
app = angular.module 'myApp', []

class facetCtrl

  constructor: (@$scope) ->
    @$scope[fn] = @[fn] for fn in [
      'facetGroupSelected'
    ]

  facetGroupSelected: (facetGroup) =>
    console.log(facetGroup)

app.controller 'facetCtrl', [
  '$http'
  facetCtrl'
]
```

The directive's coffee:

```
app = angular.module 'myApp'

facetDirective = ->
  replace: true
  restrict: 'A'
  templateUrl: '..path/to/template'
  scope:
    notify: '&'
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    scope.selectFacet = ($event) ->
      scope.notify('someFacetGroup')

app.directive 'facet', [
  'facetDirective'
]
```

Somewhere along the line, however, my function arguments are getting dropped. The function call from the directive triggers the parent controller's function, but like I said, the arguments don't make it. Are coffee scopes (`__bind.apply`, etc) breaking something?

Comment: Wow, reading this has made me hate coffeescript.

Comment: You get used to it. I was really averse to this style of class-controllers at first, but now I find them much easier to maintain, read, and modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `notify` you need to specify the argument in a slightly different way:

```
$scope.notify( { facet: 'someFacetGroup' } );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was this a recent angular change?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not sure if that was different in earlier versions.